# mysql_query where statement

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I am retrieving values from the url with the GET method and then using a if statement to determine of they are there then query them against the database to only show those items that match them, i get an unknown error with your request. here is my code

```
$province = $_GET['province'];
$city = $_GET['city'];

if(isset($province) && isset($city) ) {         
  $results3 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                            FROM generalinfo 
                           WHERE province = $province 
                             AND city = $city  ") 
                       or die( "An unknown error occurred with your request");          
} else {             
  $results3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM generalinfo");  
} /*if statement ends*/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need single-quotes round your strings in SQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM generalinfo WHERE province='$province' AND city='$city'"
```

Note that constructing the query in this way could leave you at risk of an SQL injection vulnerabillity. Consider using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) instead.

```
"SELECT * FROM generalinfo WHERE province='" .
mysql_real_escape_string($province) . "' AND city='" .
mysql_real_escape_string($city) . "'"
```

Comment: +1 because the only correct way to deal with user input is to escape it.

Comment: +1 answer without a security hole in it. Consider also parameterised queries (`mysqli`/PDO).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and this worked perfectly and I included the escapes option.